# Bibliography for self-study, after having completed Поехали 2.2?

Tags: resource-request, self-learning, russian

Let's assume I've solved all exercises of Поехали, Поехали 2.1 and Поехали 2.2. What books would you recommend me, in order to continue my studies of the Russian language? So, what's next?

I don't mind English books, although I prefer French, or even German.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that the *Поехали* books are general language-learning textbooks. Could you try to describe the level (in CEFR terms) these books help you reach?

Comment: @Tsundoku I think they were made to take a person up to, and including B1. (I'm not sure though... )